# YUI3 - Modification of Tabs

Tags: yui3, tabview

I am experimenting with the [YUI3](http://yuilibrary.com/) [TabView](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tabview/) component. Using this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NKKrQ/4/), how is it possible to disable one of the tabs (maybe using the [`Tab`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Tab.html) object)? I tried to find different examples but the [only few that I found](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tabview/tabview-basic.html) only showed how to actually create the tabs.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following:

```
tabview.item(1).disable();
```

but the tab is still clickable and stays in normal state although the class 'yui-tab-disabled' is added to the li-element.

**UPDATE 2:**

I managed to disable the second tab by using the following code:

```
tabview.item(1)
    .disable()
    .on('selectedChange', function () {
        return false;
    });
```

**The question now is: How to enable the tab again?**

Answer (score 1):

Solved! In order for the disabling and enabling of fields to work, one must include the following code snippet after the `TabView` declaration:

```
tabview.on('tab:click', function (e) {
    //  Prevent the browser from navigating to the URL specified by the 
    //  anchor's href attribute.
    if (e.target.get('disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.domEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

A full example can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NKKrQ/6/).